# A function twice differentiable exercise

Tags: calculus

We are given the function $f=f\left(u,v\right):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \:\mathbb{R}$, a function twice differentiable which has the property: $$\frac{∂^2f}{∂u^2}\left(u,v\right)=\frac{∂^2f}{∂v^2}\left(u,v\right)$$

Find the constant $a$ so that the functions $g\left(x,y\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $F=fog$ verify the equation: $$\frac{∂^2F}{∂u^2}\left(x,y\right)=0$$ for any $\left(x,y\right)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

I'm honestly clueless regarding this exercise, as I don't have any examples on how to solve it. Could anyone give me a few pointers?

Comment: maybe chain rule on multi variable functions needs to be used

Answer (score 1):

you can have

$$g(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 \\ 1 & a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}  x+y \\ x+ay\end{pmatrix}$$

The function F can be written,

$$F(x,y)=f(x+y, x+ay)$$

I guess you can complete the rest by using chain rule.